# How to remove items from array that are smaller than 20 characters?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have an array in Java.
I need to remove the items that are smaller than 20 characters.
Is this possible and how?

Comment: It's possible simply by removing items from array that are smaller than 20 characters.

Comment: just check if it has more than 20 characters and remove it :D

Comment: Iterate your array and check the length then simply remove items from array that are smaller than 20 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code, download common lang jar from apache url:http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache//commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang3-3.3.2-bin.zip

```
String[] arr = {"1","ab","aaa","sdfsdfew","ssdd"};
for(String s : arr){
    if(s.length()>3){
        arr = ArrayUtils.removeElement(arr, s);
    }
}

System.out.println(ArrayUtils.toString(arr));
```

Comment: This doesn't remove an element from the array, it creates a new array each time.

Comment: Yes, you're right, each time will return a new array. I'm Just provide the very useful ArrayUtils class to use. :)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java are fixed-size, just like in C. You can't *remove* an item from it, you can only update its value. The value can also be `null`, which may serve your purpose.

However, it is not advised to use arrays for your use case; instead use a `List` implementation. `ArrayList` is the default choice and a `LinkedList` may make sense for a huge amount of additions and deletions in the middle of the list.

With Java 8, the best approach is to use the Streams API:

```
List<String> withLongStringsDiscarded = 
   myStringList.stream().filter(s -> s.length() <= 20).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each of them, check the size using .length() function, and create the array accordingly..

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();


for (String str : strArray) {
    if (str.length() <= 20) {
         values.add(str);
    }

}

values.toArray();
```

Comment: Don't expect to provide full solution for this kind of cases.

Comment: I thought that he's a newbee.. so gave that straight away.. Have you down voted for that ?? Just because i thought he's a newbee

Comment: Your help newbee takes as a bad habit.

Comment: In that case, it applies to everyone who gave the answer... Right ??

Comment: Yes, Others are not provide direct answer but you

Comment: I am not getting your definition of complete answer.. but anyways, will keep in mind your remarks